# Update a record using Hibernate, Primefaces and Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I am using integration of `spring 3` `hibernate 4` `jsf` and `primefaces`.
in my datatable i can `insert` and `delete` a record, but my update code does not work and can not update the tables and the database. i don't want to use primefaces `cell editor`, i want a `command button` perform the update. but when i click the command button it delete the cells (fields) in database and datatable except personel_id field. please help me to have correct code.
[image]
when i edit fields and click the update button:
[image]
**personelDao.java**

```
public class PersonelDao implements IPersonelDao {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public void addPersonel(Personel personel) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(personel);
    }
    public Personel updatePersonel(Personel personel) {

final Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
if(session.contains(personel)){
    session.update(personel);
} else {
    personel = (Personel) session.merge(personel);
}
return personel;
}
public void deletePersonel(Personel personel) {
            getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().delete(personel);
        }
    }
```

**personelservice.java**

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class PersonelService implements IPersonelService{
    IPersonelDao personeldao;
    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public void addPersonel(Personel personel) {
        getPersoneldao().addPersonel(personel);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public void updatePersonel(Personel personel){
        getPersoneldao().updatePersonel(personel);
    }
    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public void deletePersonel(Personel personel) {
        getPersoneldao().deletePersonel(personel);
    }
}
```

**personelbean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name="personelMB")
@RequestScoped
public class PersonelBean implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{PersonelService}")
    IPersonelService personelservice;
    List<Personel> personelList;
    private int personel_id;
    private String pname;
    private String pfamily;
    private String paddress;
    private String pphone;

    //getter and setter
    public void addPersonel(){
            Personel personel=new Personel();
            personel.setPaddress(getPaddress());
            personel.setPersonel_id(getPersonel_id());
            personel.setPfamily(getPfamily());
            personel.setPname(getPname());
            personel.setPphone(getPphone());
            getPersonelservice().addPersonel(personel);
            reset();
    }

    public void deletePersonel(int personel_id){
            Personel personel=(Personel)personelservice.getPersonelId(personel_id);
            getPersonelservice().deletePersonel(personel);
    }

    public void update(int personel_id){
        Personel personel=(Personel)personelservice.getPersonelId(personel_id);
        personel.setPaddress(getPaddress());
        personel.setPfamily(getPfamily());
        personel.setPname(getPname());
        personel.setPphone(getPphone());
        getPersonelservice().updatePersonel(personel);
    }
}
```

**personel.xhtml**

```
    <h2>مشاهده اطلاعات پرسنل</h2>   
     <h:form  prependId="false">  
      <p:dataTable id="pdataTable" var="personel" value="#{personelMB.personelList}" rowKey="#{personelMB.personel_id}" editable="true"
         >  
            <f:facet name="header">  
                اطلاعات پرسنل 
            </f:facet>  
              <p:column> 
             <f:facet name="header">  
                   شماره پرسنلی  
                </f:facet>  
                <h:outputText value="#{personel.personel_id}" />  
                <f:facet name="footer">  
                    کدملی 
                </f:facet>  
            </p:column>  
      <p:column headerText="نام">
            <p:inputText value="#{personel.pname}" size="5"/>
                 </p:column>  
      <p:column headerText="نام خانوادگی"> 
             <p:inputText value="#{personel.pfamily}" size="5"/>
                </p:column>  
      <p:column headerText="آدرس"> 
            <p:inputText value="#{personel.paddress}" size="5"/>
            </p:column>  
       <p:column headerText="تلفن"> 
                <p:inputText value="#{personel.pphone}" size="5"/> 
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="حذف">
          <f:facet name="حذف">
             <h:outputText value="" />
          </f:facet>
          <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="حذف"
                           actionListener="#{personelMB.deletePersonel(personel.personel_id)}"  update="@form" ajax="true"/>
       </p:column>
       <p:column headerText="ويرايش">
      <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="ويرایش"
                           actionListener="#{personelMB.update(personel.personel_id)}"  update="@form" ajax="true"/>
</p:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">  
            تعداد رکورد#{fn:length(personelMB.getPersonelList())} میباشد.  
        </f:facet>  

    </p:dataTable>
```

**personel.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBLPERSONEL")
public class Personel {
    @Id
    @Column(name="PERSONEL_ID")
    private int personel_id;
    @Column(name="PNAME")
    private String pname;
    @Column(name="PFAMILY")
    private String pfamily;
    @Column(name="PADDRESS")
    private String paddress;
    @Column(name="PPHONE")
    private String pphone;
    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Manager manager;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="personel")
    private Set<Stufftransfer> stufftransfers;
    public Personel(){

    }
    //getter and setter
}
```

trace:

```
Hibernate: update TBLPERSONEL set PADDRESS=?, PFAMILY=?, PNAME=?, PPHONE=? where PERSONEL_ID=?
Hibernate: select personel0_.PERSONEL_ID as PERSONEL1_1_, personel0_.PADDRESS as PADDRESS1_, personel0_.PFAMILY as PFAMILY1_, personel0_.PNAME as PNAME1_, personel0_.PPHONE as PPHONE1_ from TBLPERSONEL personel0_
Hibernate: select manager0_.ID as ID0_1_, manager0_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD0_1_, manager0_.PERSONEL_ID as PERSONEL3_0_1_, personel1_.PERSONEL_ID as PERSONEL1_1_0_, personel1_.PADDRESS as PADDRESS1_0_, personel1_.PFAMILY as PFAMILY1_0_, personel1_.PNAME as PNAME1_0_, personel1_.PPHONE as PPHONE1_0_ from TBLMANAGER manager0_ left outer join TBLPERSONEL personel1_ on manager0_.ID=personel1_.PERSONEL_ID where manager0_.ID=?
Hibernate: select manager0_.ID as ID0_1_, manager0_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD0_1_, manager0_.PERSONEL_ID as PERSONEL3_0_1_, personel1_.PERSONEL_ID as PERSONEL1_1_0_, personel1_.PADDRESS as PADDRESS1_0_, personel1_.PFAMILY as PFAMILY1_0_, personel1_.PNAME as PNAME1_0_, personel1_.PPHONE as PPHONE1_0_ from TBLMANAGER manager0_ left outer join TBLPERSONEL personel1_ on manager0_.ID=personel1_.PERSONEL_ID where manager0_.ID=?
Hibernate: select manager0_.ID as ID0_1_, manager0_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD0_1_, manager0_.PERSONEL_ID as PERSONEL3_0_1_, personel1_.PERSONEL_ID as PERSONEL1_1_0_, personel1_.PADDRESS as PADDRESS1_0_, personel1_.PFAMILY as PFAMILY1_0_, personel1_.PNAME as PNAME1_0_, personel1_.PPHONE as PPHONE1_0_ from TBLMANAGER manager0_ left outer join TBLPERSONEL personel1_ on manager0_.ID=personel1_.PERSONEL_ID where manager0_.ID=?
Hibernate: select personel0_.PERSONEL_ID as PERSONEL1_1_, personel0_.PADDRESS as PADDRESS1_, personel0_.PFAMILY as PFAMILY1_, personel0_.PNAME as PNAME1_, personel0_.PPHONE as PPHONE1_ from TBLPERSONEL personel0_
Hibernate: select manager0_.ID as ID0_1_, manager0_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD0_1_, manager0_.PERSONEL_ID as PERSONEL3_0_1_, personel1_.PERSONEL_ID as PERSONEL1_1_0_, personel1_.PADDRESS as PADDRESS1_0_, personel1_.PFAMILY as PFAMILY1_0_, personel1_.PNAME as PNAME1_0_, personel1_.PPHONE as PPHONE1_0_ from TBLMANAGER manager0_ left outer join TBLPERSONEL personel1_ on manager0_.ID=personel1_.PERSONEL_ID where manager0_.ID=?
Hibernate: select manager0_.ID as ID0_1_, manager0_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD0_1_, manager0_.PERSONEL_ID as PERSONEL3_0_1_, personel1_.PERSONEL_ID as PERSONEL1_1_0_, personel1_.PADDRESS as PADDRESS1_0_, personel1_.PFAMILY as PFAMILY1_0_, personel1_.PNAME as PNAME1_0_, personel1_.PPHONE as PPHONE1_0_ from TBLMANAGER manager0_ left outer join TBLPERSONEL personel1_ on manager0_.ID=personel1_.PERSONEL_ID where manager0_.ID=?
Hibernate: select manager0_.ID as ID0_1_, manager0_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD0_1_, manager0_.PERSONEL_ID as PERSONEL3_0_1_, personel1_.PERSONEL_ID as PERSONEL1_1_0_, personel1_.PADDRESS as PADDRESS1_0_, personel1_.PFAMILY as PFAMILY1_0_, personel1_.PNAME as PNAME1_0_, personel1_.PPHONE as PPHONE1_0_ from TBLMANAGER manager0_ left outer join TBLPERSONEL personel1_ on manager0_.ID=personel1_.PERSONEL_ID where manager0_.ID=?
```

Answer (score 0):

Define transactional only in the method and assign propagation, if you define "transactional" on class this is apply for all methods.

Change for personelservice.java:

```
//@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class PersonelService implements IPersonelService{
    IPersonelDao personeldao;
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void addPersonel(Personel personel) {
        getPersoneldao().addPersonel(personel);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void updatePersonel(Personel personel){
        getPersoneldao().updatePersonel(personel);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void deletePersonel(Personel personel) {
        getPersoneldao().deletePersonel(personel);
    }
}
```

Regart,

Manu Navarro.

PS: Forgive for my English little fluid

Comment: Dear Manu, thank you for your reply. i did what you said but my problem did not solve.

Answer (score 0):

to prevent session loss problem when update, changes in dao:

```
public class PersonelDao implements IPersonelDao {
    ...
    public Personel updatePersonel(Personel personel) {
        final Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        if(session.contains(personel)){
            session.update(personel);
        } else {
            personel = (Personel) session.merge(personel);
        }
        return personel;
    }
    ...
}
```

thus if the entity is not in session will be forced to link it with the merge.

You also have to retrieve the object returned by the merge, you may have had to force and changed the reference in memory.

Regards,

Comment: dear Manu, thank you for your pay attention. but it did not work too. i am really confused. when i edit the data table cell and click update command button, the data disapear from database and datatable row.

Comment: Manu, i have edited the post add the trace. would you please take a look. special thanks

Comment: start it in debug mode, looking to pass the correct lines, if it gives an error, the error attached and the line where it occurs.

Comment: I have not enough level of English, you speak Spanish?

Comment: Now I can not, I can in 8 hours, 20:00 UTC+1